# Speed up Excel 2016 Query Refresh Time when Importing Tables from Access 2016

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access, excel-2016

I have a system where there are about 30 Excel 2016 templates that all pull prices for the items on each template from a single, master Access 2016 file. These are all located on a server that anyone with access may open. The templates are used to request specific items to be sent to a job site, while also tracking its price so it can be charged to that job. The goal of having a single master file with all the pricing is so that every time a price changes (which is fairly often), I don't have to update the price in every single template.

Right now, I have an `Auto_Open` module in each of these forms that refreshes the data from the Access file every time a copy of the template is opened. This ensures that the prices for the items that the project managers request for their job is updated every time they use the sheet. This usually completes in less than a second, and it updates all the information just fine. Here's the code:

```
Sub Auto_Open()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("Import Sheet").Unprotect Password:="secret"
Sheets("Import Sheet").Visible = True 'for some reason the data doesn't like to refresh unless the sheet is visible
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone 'ensures every connection refreshes
Sheets("Import Sheet").Visible = False
Sheets("Import Sheet").Unprotect Password:="secret"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Recently, Microsoft put out an update to Excel that combines data imports and transformations into a new single section under the Data tab called "Get and Transform Data." Along with this update, new wizards were released to import data under the "Get Data" button in this section. The old "Legacy Wizards" are still available, which is what I was using and what has been working with the above code.

I looked for information on this new tab, but the only usable info was a Microsoft support web page, and it shows the old organization with separated sections, found [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Get-Transform-in-Excel-2016-881c63c6-37c5-4ca2-b616-59e18d75b4de). So, I did my own testing, and I found the following differences:

1. It's possible to change how the data imports in the new wizard, i.e. I can delete rows and columns that I don't want. (This is particularly valuable for what I'm doing since some of the information for each item isn't used to calculate price, such as the supplier or the individual break down for shipping and the actual cost of the item).
2. I can't have a password on the new wizard, it doesn't let me open the Access file if it is password-protected. If someone has a solution to this one too, that'd be great.
3. The connection types are different. In the legacy wizards, the connection type is simply "Microsoft Access Database." However, the new wizards show the connection type as an "OLE DB Query."
4. Finally, the legacy wizard shows the import as a "connection," while the new wizard imports it as a "query."

My worry is that in the next version of Excel, the legacy wizards will no longer be available, so I would like to update to the new wizards. Further, it would also be beneficial to be able to only import specific rows and columns out of the Access file, which I can't do using the legacy wizards.

However, one of these template sheets imports 11 different tables, which ended up taking about 30 seconds to update when I tried opening a new worksheet based off of the template. This is way too long to be efficient or worth the benefits of the new wizard.

In the [connection properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jJZ4.png) of the tables imported with the new wizard, there's a few options that I messed around with. First, I deleted my `Auto_Open` module and tried to use the "Refresh data when opening the file" option, this ended up taking a minute to update all of the tables, and it forced me to unlock the sheet, which I would *strongly prefer* to remain locked. Second, I tried the "Enable Fast Data Load" and "Enable background refresh," and I was able to get it down to 17 seconds, but that still is a pretty long time to wait every time you open a file. I would also prefer not to use background refresh, since the time spent on each sheet may not be enough to guarantee every price is updated, especially on some of the files with 10+ imported tables. Anyway, I attempted ever possible combination and I was only able to reduce the time to, on average, 20 seconds.

I guess the **big questions** of this post are:

1. How can I speed up the refresh time for the imported tables when I use the new wizards? And if I can't, how can I ensure that I will still have access to the legacy wizards?
2. Is it possible to lock an Access file while using the new wizards, and how do I do that?

The CAD technician that I work with is also communicating with some of his contacts within Microsoft to see if he can get any information about the future availability of the legacy wizards. If necessary, I can comment a few example files (with fake prices, obviously) so anyone can mess around with them.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you can use .xlsm files, then you should use ADODB for connecting to the database.

Here is a good tutorial:
http://www.onlinepclearning.com/import-from-access-to-excel/

You can execute SQL statments to modify the database.

However if your database is password protected you will need to include that in the connection string,
and since it is very easy to crack protected vba projects, the password will not be safe at all.

Comment: I don't know too terribly much about SQL, so I'll look into that some more. I've gotten a few responses from the Microsoft team, and they definitely see that there is an issue. I'm only using a password so it's not super easy for the guys who have access to the server to edit it, they aren't super tech savvy, so the password is only there to keep them at bay, not to protect against hackers. Otherwise, I'll do some checking into SQL.